# EntityFramework add-Migration can not process success

Tags: entity-framework

I have already install entityframework
and then i run this

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

it shows No context type was found in the assembly 'GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test'.

then i run this

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName "GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test.GLRISCRM_SMS_Context" -ProjectName "GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test" -StartUpProjectName "GLRISCRM.SMS.DbMigrations.Test" -ConnectionStringName "GLRISCRM_SMS_Context" -Verbose
```

it show

> Using StartUp project 'GLRISCRM.SMS.DbMigrations.Test'.
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException:
>   Migrations have already been enabled in project
>   'GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test'. To overwrite the existing migrations
>   configuration, use the -Force parameter.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c_*DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b*_0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Migrations have already been enabled in project
>   'GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test'. To overwrite the existing migrations
>   configuration, use the -Force parameter.

then i run this

```
add-Migration
```

cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: update1

it show

> ```
> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
> 'GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test'. (In Visual Studio you can use the
> Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a
> migrations configuration).
> ```

how can i run success the add-Migration
who can help me
this is my Configuration

>

```
     namespace GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test.Migrations
     {
         using System;
         using System.Data.Entity;
         using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
         using System.Linq;

 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test.GLRISCRM_SMS_Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(GLRISCRM.SMS.Dal.Test.GLRISCRM_SMS_Context context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I can not find any problem

Comment: my environment is   in MVC4, Entity Framework 5.00， vs2010

Comment: where is your context type. is it on test project or Dal Library

Comment: I found the reason.my version is not right ，i think this is a bug between Package Manager Console and dll refereces. after update entityframework by Package Manager Console all the problem is solve.